# Is there a api function for a MacOS Store based application to start itself at a certain time

Tags: xcode, frameworks

Under Windows i use the Task Scheduler, under linux cron job to start an application at a certain time, even if the cron job would work on MacOS, i wonder if there is a apple conform way to start my application at certain times and to start the computer from hibernation.

I know that cron jobs would work, but i doubt that this would ever pass its way through a apple review.

The reason for this question is that the application is working a tv player with the ability to record DVB transmissions. I dislike the idea to "force" the user to keep the program running in background.